# Can't get a function to execute before another onClick function

Tags: jquery, validation, javascript

I have a form that is submitting using an onClick function which works perfectly. However, now I'm trying to get it to validate the form by checking if there is any text in a particular textarea in order that the form may submit by calling the mentioned function.

Here is the HTML: (extraneous html ommitted)

```
<textarea name="employee_statement" onblur="checkMaxLengthT(this,'Employee Statement',2000);" class="inputTextareaFu60R employeeStmtInput">test</textarea>
<input name="save" type="button" class="btn6022" value="Save" onClick="checkEmployeeStmtInput();compare3dates(onset_date,report_date,fatal_death_date,'caseUpdateCase.do')">
```

Here is the jQuery function:

```
checkEmployeeStmtInput(){
    var employeeStmt = $('textarea.employeeStmtInput').val();
        if (employeeStmt == ''){
            alert('You must provide an Employee Statement.');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Essentially, now, the original onClick function never gets called. If I remove the `checkEmployeeStmtInput()` function call, it does work.

Comment: You can submit the form after your  `if` statement for example.

Comment: @dihakz Try putting a `,` instead of a `;` after `checkEmployeeStmtInput()` in the `onClick` bit.

Comment: Also, if you're already using jQuery, why not drop the `onClick` bit into a `.click()` function?

Comment: I bet the console shows some error regarding `checkEmployeeStmtInput`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @BalintBako I tried that, but for some reason the checkEmployeeStmtInput() function is never called, so putting the other function after the if statement doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock I tried the comma, and that did not work. I'm working with another team member that doesn't know jQuery, so that is why it is using an onClick handler and not the .click() function.

Comment: @dihakz Does your `checkEmployee` function have `function` before it? Meaning, is it written as `function checkEmployeeStmtInput() {}`?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock ARGH! That was it. That was the problem. Thank you for pointing out my stupidity! ;)

Comment: @dihakz Glad I could help. I put it as an answer as well so that it wouldn't be buried in the comments.

Comment: In that case the console would have shown a syntax error. Have a look at the link I posted in earlier comment to solve future issues by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `function` before `checkEmployeeStmtInput()`, so it would be written as `function checkEmployeeStmtInput() {}`.

Answer (score 0):

call this function,this may help you.

```
 function validate(){

    if(any textfield=="empty"){
    alert("field is empty");
    return false;
    }
    else{
    return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot call ANY function before the other one. It causes BOTH functions to fail.

Comment: then include the code inside validate() in your main validation function instead of creating different functions.Dont worry the form will not be submitted unless return false is mentioned when field is empty